# tslib: read from all suitable input devices?

Tags: qt, touchscreen

Is there some way to use a touchscreen *without* explicitely specifying the exact input device?

Let me explain in depth...

My host has a number of input devices:

```
$ ls -al /dev/input/
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          200 Jul 11 16:09 .
drwxr-xr-x   11 root     root         4580 Jul 10 15:31 ..
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      13,  64 Jan  1  1970 event0
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      13,  65 Jan  1  1970 event1
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      13,  66 Jan  1  1970 event2
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      13,  95 Jan  1  1970 event99
crw-rw----    1 root     root      13,  63 Jan  1  1970 mice
crw-rw----    1 root     root      10, 223 Jan  1  1970 uinput
```

One of these input devices (usually event2) is the touchscreen thats connected via USB.
My problem is that...

- the eventX device might not always be event2
- the touchscreen might be unplugged and plugged in again (that will result in a different eventX device) and the touchscreen should work again **without needing to restart the application**
- the USB host might occasionally do a reset (because of other problems) resulting in a USB disconnect and USB reconnect of the touchscreen

The application is a Qt embedded 4.7 application running in full screen mode, using **tslib** as touchscreen driver.

For another project with similar issues I already wrote a little daemon (I called it "eventbundler") that reads data from all /dev/input/eventX devices and sends the data to a named pipe (FIFO). However, tslib won't accept that fifo as input device (`QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=tslib:/dev/input/eventbundler-mouse`) - probably because the IOCTLs to query the device capabilities don't work (it says "`selected device is not a touchscreen I understand`").

Anyway what I'd need is that *tslib* should somehow autodetect the touchscreen device and read from it even if had been unplugged for a moment.

Any hints?

I'm willing to alter the Qt source code if that is of any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is no solution, but there's an [issue](https://github.com/kergoth/tslib/issues/52) for tslib that very vaguely describes your problem. If ideas regarding path selection are discussed there, it at least might *help* to solve this someday.